# Pygame image used as screen then final transformed to screen

Tags: python, pygame

I want to be able to stretch a screen without needing to stretch each image individually.

I have a image I use as the screen, then when I have the final product I transform the image to the size of the screen and blit it to the screen.

But the images blit onto the main image do not transform with the main image, and comes out as its first size.

You can find the current version here:
https://gist.github.com/gideonjvisser/eca7506f483c51edf93c/

Here's the script:

---

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import Color

chosen_resolution = (400,200)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(chosen_resolution)
screen_rect = screen.get_rect()

in_game_resolution = (800,600)
screen_image = pygame.Surface(in_game_resolution)
screen_image_rect = screen_image.get_rect()

image_on_in_game = pygame.image.load("image.png").convert_alpha()
image_on_in_game = pygame.transform.scale(image_on_in_game, (469,669)) #to fit on in_game_resolution

print screen_rect
print screen_image_rect

while(True):
    screen_image.fill(Color('white'))
    screen_image.blit(image_on_in_game, (0,0))
    screen_image = pygame.transform.scale(screen_image, chosen_resolution)
    screen.blit(screen_image, (0,0))
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code almost works. The issue is that, in your while loop, you overwrite your static resolution intermediate surface with the scaled version. Try replacing the while loop with this:

```
while True:
    screen_image.fill(Color('white'))
    screen_image.blit(image_on_in_game, (0,0))
    screen.blit(pygame.transform.scale(screen_image, chosen_resolution), (0,0))
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Now the pre-scaled buffer should remain the right size and actually be scaled to fit the real screen's size.